# Salt and Pepper impulse Denoising opencv

Tags: opencv, image-processing, filtering, median, noise-reduction

I am creating a generic method to work on salt and pepper noise and variants. The example images are as shown below :

[image]
[image]
[image]

I tried few methods, such as

- Median filter from scipy
- Selective Adaptive Median Filter by Jayanta Das et al.

The closest result was on Image 3, with Median filter, giving the closest result to the original image with no noise.

These are my following doubts :

1. Can we consider these noises as salt and pepper noise? Is there something else that I am missing?
2. What could be the better suggested method? Currently, I am planning to implement Switching Median filter by Pei-Eng et al, but I would like to know if this could be the right track.

The originals that I am trying to get closer to:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I assume you added the noise to the images? Salt and pepper noise is a very unrealistic noise model for medical imaging. It was relevant way back when digital imaging was new and individual sensor elements could be broken or even malfunction temporarily.

Comment: I got the images as the dataset as the images to solve/work on. I did not add the noise @CrisLuengo

Comment: If it’s a class exercise, follow your teacher’s recommendation for which methods to use. I think only the 3rd image has salt & pepper noise, the other ones seem different to me.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know these noises are not natural and estimating them is almost impossible. As a simple and handy method, median filter is the best. Since the presence of the noise is too much, the images are corrupted and there is a huge loss in the image information. In this situation, the best practice is to use deep learning method, because they can restore the impaired parts of the image to a desirable level.

I found this paper, promising for such purpose but you would find more resources:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.10039.pdf

In this page also you will find many strong deep learning methods and codes for denoising image:

https://github.com/z-bingo/awesome-image-denoising-state-of-the-art